# Toggle display the child div once the parent div is validated

Tags: php, jquery

Straight to the point: I have a parent and a child and they are connected through the onclick=showMe("",this) line. The problem here, is if the parent is validated, it will check the checkbox, but it won't show the corresponding child. Here is an excerp:

```
    {

    <?php
    //Getting the Category ids
    $ids=$detail['details_category_ids'];

    //Trying to explode into integers
    $cat_array = array_map('intval', explode(' | ',$ids));

    foreach($cat_val as $ids=>$ids_value){
    $cat_array2[$ids_value]=$cat_array[$ids];
    }

    ?>

    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Parent1</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" id="chb1" value="1" <?php echo ($cat_array2[1]=='1')                 ? 'checked' :''; ?> onclick="showMe('level_2', this)"> Level 1
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="level_2" style="display:none">
    <hr>
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Child1</label>
    <label class="checkbox inline span13" style="margin-left:10px;">
    <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" id="idCheckbox1" value="9" <?php echo         ($cat_array2[1]=='1') ? 'checked' :''; ?> onclick="showMe('pb-counter', this)">Counter
    </label>
    </div>
    </div>

    }
```

And here is the jQuery file that I was testing out:

```
    $(document).ready(
    (function(){
    if('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length{
    $('.child_id',this).toggle();
    }
    });
```

-> Basicly, I want the child to show when the parent is validated. Without clicking the checkbox. And if there is a better way to do it, I'm all ears.

Comment: This question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) listener and validate your form as soon as something gets changed.

When certain requirements are met, show the rest of the form.